# How to structure DB access in ASPNET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASPNET MVC and I'm trying to understand which is the best way to work with it; I have a DB structure and I'm using EF4 that generates the DbModel.edmx.

I could invoke Entities directly from the Controller but I've read somewhere that it could be better to embed all DB calls to a Repository Class and consume it from Controllers. Is it the right way to work in ASPNET MVC3?

How can DataValidation be handled with this structure?

Comment: `...better to embed all DB calls to a Repository Class and consume it from Controllers` That's the best practice.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check NerdDinner which is done by high profile programmers and there is a step-by-step book as well. It also uses patterns such as Repository, ViewModel, DataValidation, etc.

Source code: http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/
**Free** book: http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-321793.html

There is a branch for **ASP.Net MVC 3** in the source code of NerdDinner. :)